# Tell Xcode that two radio buttons are "connected" (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to do my first Mac application, and I would like to use two radio buttons in order to be able to select only one of two. I'm doing this application in Swift. Any help?

Comment: what do you mean by connected ? If user selects one radio button you want to select another automatically is that the case or something else.Please explain

Comment: No I don't mean that, I mean like in html, when you put two radios in the same <form>, you can only select one of them, but it is not happening in my app because I don't know how to tell xcode that they are in the same ""form""

Comment: Put the buttons in the same NSMatrix. That should make them work how you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly would just use a action to know when one was clicked and in that action add code to deselect the other one.

It may not be the cleanest and most professional way.

I don't know... It's just a thought. I'm pretty young, and I know some basics. Just trying to.

---

Update 2: I've looked around the web... and apparently it isn't a built in function.

Comment: I understand what you mean but the point is that radio buttons are made to be singly selected, so for sure there is another fast way, but thank you anyway

Comment: Glad to help. Have you searched Apples documentations? There should be something there.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "Radio Group" in XCode. It will add two radio buttons where just one of them is selected at the time.